# How to distinguish between minus sign and negative number in nom?

Tags: rust, parser-generator, nom

Using the parser generator [nom](https://github.com/Geal/nom), how can I write a parser which extracts the difference of the minus sign in the terms `1-2` and `1*-2` ?

In the first example, I expect the tokens `1`, `-` and `2`. In the second the "minus" sign specifies the number being negative. The expected tokens are `1`, `*` and `-2`. Not `1`, `*`, `-` and `2`.

How can I make nom stateful, with user-defined states such as `expect_literal: bool`?

Comment: This isn't a nom-specific problem, it's just purely a conceptual parsing / grammar question. Moreover, it's a very common parsing problem; it doesn't appear that you've done the appropriate amount of research before asking this question.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that state isn't required to address this.

Comment: See also [How to parse an arithmetic string expression with negative numbers and minus signs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52996557); [Evaluate code, differentiating between minus and negative?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33158960); [How to differentiate '-' operator from a negative number for a tokenizer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26529711); [How Compiler distinguishes minus and negative number during parser process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27478834)

Comment: [And many more similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+parser+negative+minus)

Comment: @Shepmaster Thank you for posting answers which do not cover that question. They all solve a similar problem, when someone writes a parser from scratch, but not the actual problem using nom. The question here targets specifically the usage of nom for such a standard use-case.

Comment: Please provide your best attempt at creating a parser in the form of a [mcve], with a specific implementation question.

Comment: `nom` isn't a parser, or a parser generator. `nom` is a library for easily crafting parsers in a parser-combinator fashion. How you tokenize is entirely up to you, and the linked questions address exactly what you're asking about.

Comment: @Zarenor But `nom` provides some features helping you to solve problems like this without reinventing the wheel. As you can see in the answer below. Sure you could post-process things like that. But often this makes things unnecessary complicated. And non of the linked questions addresses what I was asking about.

Comment: @Matthias If your answer is satisfactory to you, very well, but you're using `nom_locate` (a crate which isn't `nom`, or made by the creator of `nom`) and making a stateful parser, which does things in an unorthodox manner. I wouldn't rate it a particularly idiomatic solution, or very extensible. If it's what you wanted, I'm happy, but it isn't the orthodox way to do things, and it may have different performance characteristics, or be harder to refactor later if you need to extend the code to do more.

Comment: @Zarenor. `nom_locate` is a kind of a helper crate for `nom`. You could write the needed lines of code by yourself... But why to reinvent the wheel? What do you mean with *unorthodox manner*? All the linked questions are either using states or a look behind technique (or using `yacc`). Do you mean the look behind approach would be more orthodox in `nom`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I found for now is using [nom_locate](https://crates.io/crates/nom_locate) with a span defined as

```rust
use nom_locate::LocatedSpanEx;

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct LexState {
    pub accept_literal: bool,
}

type Span<'a> = LocatedSpanEx<&'a str, LexState>;
```

Then you can modify the state via

```rust
fn set_accept_literal(
    value: bool,
    code: IResult<Span, TokenPayload>,
) -> IResult<Span, TokenPayload> {
    match code {
        Ok(mut span) => {
            span.0.extra.accept_literal = value;
            Ok(span)
        }
        _ => code,
    }
}
```

where `TokenPayload` is an enum representing my token content.

Now you can write the operator parser:

```rust
fn mathematical_operators(code: Span) -> IResult<Span, TokenPayload> {
    set_accept_literal(
        true,
        alt((
            map(tag("*"), |_| TokenPayload::Multiply),
            map(tag("/"), |_| TokenPayload::Divide),
            map(tag("+"), |_| TokenPayload::Add),
            map(tag("-"), |_| TokenPayload::Subtract),
            map(tag("%"), |_| TokenPayload::Remainder),
        ))(code),
    )
}
```

And the integer parser as:

```rust
fn parse_integer(code: Span) -> IResult<Span, TokenPayload> {
    let chars = "1234567890";
    // Sign ?
    let (code, sign) = opt(tag("-"))(code)?;
    let sign = sign.is_some();
    if sign && !code.extra.accept_literal {
        return Err(nom::Err::Error((code, ErrorKind::IsNot)));
    }
    let (code, slice) = take_while(move |c| chars.contains(c))(code)?;
    match slice.fragment.parse::<i32>() {
        Ok(value) => set_accept_literal(
            false,
            Ok((code, TokenPayload::Int32(if sign { -value } else { value }))),
        ),
        Err(_) => Err(nom::Err::Error((code, ErrorKind::Tag))),
    }
}
```

This might not win a beauty contest but it works. The remaining pieces should be trivial.